# In Django project facing TypeError?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I got error in project like save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

```
def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(DealsForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
    obj.user = request.username
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Please present related views and entire block of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you call

`YouForm.save()`

instead of

`YouForm.save(request)`

Somewhere in your code.

Probably in some generic view. You have to customize view in order to pass request into form.